# Select Display fields depends on Grouping values

Tags: grid, report, filtering, grouping, birt

I know it is a basic question. I just started learning eclipse BIRT, so i cant find any related documents. I have report like following image.

[image]

In this i used **nested grouping**. In left side grouping `when i click the` **Pnematikk** it has two child like namely **1.sjekk lekkasjer 2. Sjekk lufttykket** i need to show these values in **GRID A**(Pink color highlight) but currently shown only one.

Next when click the **Sjekk lekkasjer** it's `childs` are **(OK,NOT OK]**. Now i `want to show both OK an NOT OK` fields in my **Registration Details(in My green highlighted GRID)** that is in **GRID B** . `At the same time` **GRID A** display currently selected item that is it shows only **Sjekk lekkasjer**.

I really need some guidence.

Comment: It is hard to answer without seeing the structure of the rptdesign. The grid "Registration details" seems to be inserted within the last grouping level "status" (OK, Not OK), whereas if we want to display all status it should be inserted in the footer of the parent group (group containing "sjekk lekkasjer")

Comment: @Dominique first thanks for your reply..if you want i am ready to share the rptDesign.

Comment: @Dominique http://pastebin.com/MJ8xASa9 see thin one..i really need help..

Comment: @Dominique look at my question i edited..please

Comment: I am not sure this can act as you expect with a TOC (Table Of Content), may be you should make use of report parameters to do this. A TOC is a way to navigate across the pagination of a report, but won't affect the display.

Comment: @Dominique do you have any sample projects using Javascript..if you have please send me..i need reference...

Answer (score 2):

You clearly have a group on "registration" column at the top of the table, as we can see on your screenshot there is a "Not OK" at the beginning. This is why detail rows are filtered by registration.

By looking at the .rptdesign this registration group doesn't seem to be used, and there is no aggregation defined on it. So you could just remove it and this should act as expected.

[image]

Comment: oops still same...if i delete registration then also not able to see both OK an NOT OK..